# Which is better between using IDs or styleClass while using Primefaces Ajax update to render UI components?

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2, rendering

I can use IDs of components or a styleClass used in all of the components.

```
<p:ajax event="change" process="@none" listener="#{someListener()}"
        update="@(.someStyleClass)"/>

<p:ajax event="change" process="@none" listener="#{someListener()}"
        update="someId1 someId2 someId3"/>
```

Which approach is better and why?

**EDIT: I know that CSS selector uses IDs in the background. I am not asking how it works. I am asking which is a better approach ( for maybe different cases ) and why.**

Comment: There is no good or wrong... It is a maintainability issues... Like stated in the 'answer'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused with the concept of these **CSS** selectors with the updating of **PrimeFaces** components.

Simple, if you have requirement to update just one component use **ID** selector. While, if you have numerous (more than one) components to be updated on certain action, use **CLASS** selector.

**Update:**
Although you can set comma separated IDs of components in your `update` attribute, but the difference of using **CLASS** selector would be that those components are interrelated (similar) by any mean or you don't want to use separate **ID** attribute on each component.

Comment: I don't think OP is confused... not at all . And you don't need to use class selectors,  You can also use 'type' selectors (all inputs) or...

Comment: @Kukeltje, Now I am sure, OP was confused! And OP didn't ask for the `type` selector.